# 7.1 surround sound linux (ubuntu) (steelseries arctis 7)

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

When connecting my Arctis 7, I see in my settings->audio->test only front left and front right speakers. Same in alsamixer. I've changed the default sample channels setting as said here https://wiki.debian.org/PulseAudio in /etc/pulse/daemon.conf, but it didn't seem to change anything.

I've also found this question: [How do I configure PulseAudio for 7.1 Surround Sound over HDMI?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111428/how-do-i-configure-pulseaudio-for-7-1-surround-sound-over-hdmi) but I can't seem to run that line for my setup (tried replacing hdmi with surround71, and with a few other things in this list: https://gist.github.com/JoranDox/08658296d01bb4c78e6ed5be815f2a6c )

resulting in

```
$ pasuspender -- speaker-test -D surround71 -c 8 -m FL,FC,FR,RR,RRC,RLC,RL,LFE

speaker-test 1.2.2

Playback device is surround71
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 8 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Channels count (8) not available for playbacks: Invalid argument
Setting of hwparams failed: Invalid argument
```

```
$ pasuspender -- speaker-test -D surround71:CARD=S7,DEV=0 -c 8 -m FL,FC,FR,RR,RRC,RLC,RL,LFE

speaker-test 1.2.2

Playback device is surround71:CARD=S7,DEV=0
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 8 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
Broken configuration for playback: no configurations available: Invalid argument
Setting of hwparams failed: Invalid argument
```

They say to use DTS Headphone:X on windows for 7.1 surround, is this not possible on linux? I've tried running SteelSeries Engine under wine but it didn't work out (tried 5.0, 5.4 and 5.8). I've got a windows dual boot where it does work, so if I need to get some info from there that's also possible.

Any leads?

Comment: And of course you can do your own downmixing of 7.1 to stereo in various ways on Linux. But stereo headphones are stereo headphones, they won't produce true 7.1.

Answer (score 2):

**It's not possible on Linux** (with your headphones).

Those SteelSeries Arctis headphones are a stereo (2-channel) sink.

The 7.1 is entirely virtual inside Windows 10/11 and is handled by the DTS Headphone driver, through a Windows technology that lets the DTS plugin sit "before" the stereo output and pretend to be a 7.1 output.

So on Windows, it routes: Audio -> DTS 7.1 driver (which generates a binaural stereo downmix) -> 2 channel output to headphones.

Another reason why your headphones aren't a 7.1 output is because they are wireless. There isn't enough bandwidth (even with a dedicated 2.4 GHz USB dongle) to transmit 8 channels (7.1) via wireless on ANY headset. Wireless 2.4 GHz with custom dongles tops out at around 20 kHz stereo audio, with a ~7-12 kHz microphone input (2 output sinks, 1 input sink). To get more than that, such as true 7.1 audio, you need a wired USB headset.

**The *only* headphones that can do true 3D surround on Linux are the HyperX Cloud Orbit S and the Audeze Mobius.** They are the exact same product and HyperX bought the design/technology AND manufacturing from Audeze. If you want them, you should buy the HyperX because they're owned by HP/Kingston and have good finances which have allowed them to refine the design to make it more durable than the Audeze variant, and HyperX are also more generous with warranty since they can afford to offer good warranty.

So what's special about HyperX Cloud Orbit S and Audeze Mobius?

- They present as a real 7.1 or 5.1 or 2.0 output to the operating system (you can switch mode via a hardware button). The headphones will receive true 8-channel surround audio.
- The 3D virtual surround is Waves NX which is THE best in the world, with the clearest audio. It was originally developed for music producers who hear every little detail and phasing issue, and I can report that NX has super clean sound and doesn't create the mud/phasing that other virtual surround solutions do. It's also by far the best at truly creating spatial location awareness (when I tried 5 different 3D surround solutions, NX was the only one that could create the effect of something BEHIND you).
- The headphones contain a hardware CPU inside the headphones which runs the Waves NX code for the 3D virtualization.
- So your computer outputs true 7.1 sound (8ch) and Waves NX inside the headphone virtualizes it.
- There is no software on the computer. Linux uses them perfectly like a normal audio output. All of the virtual-surround DSP software runs on the embedded CPU inside the headphones.
- The icing on the cake is that they both use the same 100mm Audeze Planar Magnetic Technology speakers, which have the cleanest, clearest sound of every headphone technology out there. This technology originally only existed in audiophile headphones. You will have extreme clarity and detail in the sound, without any mud or distortion. The speaker membranes are 4x larger than ordinary headphones.
- They support up to 5 meter long USB-2 cables (16.4 feet). So you have immense freedom to move around. And yes, being wired is a VERY worthwhile "price" for getting true 7.1 surround with the best virtual surround technology in the entire world (Waves NX) and the best speaker technology in the entire world (Planar Magnetic technology).
- There's a built-in battery which provides around 10 hours of standalone use with other devices, such as via analog 3.5mm input from a VR headset or phone. Many modern phones also support plugging the headphones into their USB-C port. The 3D surround virtualization runs in standalone mode too, so it's awesome for listening to music from your phone in what feels like a super high quality virtual concert room.

You can research more at https://www.hyperxgaming.com/en/headsets/cloud-orbit-gaming-headset, they have two variants, Orbit and Orbit S. The Orbit S is the best choice because it includes head tracking (gyroscopes) which accurately position the audio while you turn your head around. Basically as you turn your head physically, the audio will always position itself where the sound source is in relation to your physical body. It's awesome for home cinema feeling and also creates an airy sensation of not even wearing headphones at all. You can toggle those sensors on/off and it's great to have the option. Definitely get the S model.

Anyway, this is how to get surround sound headphones on Linux. The technology is also awesome while wearing VR headsets (like Oculus Quest 2). Hope it helps someone!

Comment: So sifting through the advertisement, you're saying the arctis 7 does not in fact have 7+ drivers, but instead is faking it using 2 drivers using proprietary software on Windows?

Comment: If the HyperX and Audeze headphones are connected to the PC via USB, there HAS TO BE some software as well to "output" 8 channels. How is that going to happen? Are these supported out of the box by e.g. pulse audio. How did you set one of the headphones up?