# wireplumber: How to disable auto-mute speakers when headphone is plugged in, and vice versa? Generally: How to stop it to interfere with alsa mixers?

Tags: alsa, pipewire, wireplumber

I recently switched to `pipewire` + `pipewire-pulse` + `wireplumber`.

Is it somehow possible to tell wireplumber *not* to automatically mute/ unmute unused paths?

E.g. when I plug in a plug into the headphones socket, I do *not* want my internal speakers to be muted. And I don't want headphone socket to be muted when there is apparently nothing plugged in.

(Two reasons:

1. I still want to be able to get simultaneous output -- and will mute manually when i want,
2. my machine has a hardware glitch where it spuriously detects headphone removal although it has not been removed. That makes wireplumber mute headphones and unmute internal audio, and to just do the reverse shortly after because the glitches are really short. But that created big glitches on audio output.)

With pulseaudio, I was [able to stop that by modifying `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-*`-files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/609967/how-to-stop-pulseaudio-from-muting-other-devices) (hacky, since it would not survice package upgrades, but I can write a hook to re-apply the changes after each upgrade.

How can this be achieved with wireplumber?

I want to use wireplumber to automatically connect audio sources to audio sinks.

I *do not* want wireplumber to interfere with my alsa mixer settings at all, ideally; at least not doing any auto-mute/ auto-volume-zero when devices are connected/ disconnected.

I see that wireplumber is doing it, since when I kill `wireplumber` but leave `pipewire` and `pipewire-pulse` running, auto-mute does not occur.

Regards!

Comment: If you are using multiple outputs off the same sound card, you might want to try setting its profile to "Pro Audio" if available. That will give you split controls for each port of your soundcard.

Comment: @cyqsimon: How? -- If you write a real answer that explains how to do it, and it it works, I will mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: Honestly I'm reluctant to write a full answer because audio systems are very complex in nature, and I know way too little about your specific setup to give accurate directions. So sorry about that. I will refer you to ArchLinux's [PipeWire article](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire) though. They talk about what the "Pro Audio" profile does, and how to switch device profiles in great detail.

Comment: Also note that your graphical environment's audio control widget might allow you to graphically switch profiles. For example in KDE's audio control widget, there's a hamburger menu for each device in which you can select the profile.