# Remap surround speakers over HDMI Steam OS (Steam Deck)

Tags: arch-linux, audio, pulseaudio

I recently got my Steam Deck. Love the device. But got issues with surround sound. The mapping is wrong with 5.1. It appears that side is configured as back or the other way around.

So I want to remap them manually. Pulse Volume control doesn't have this option. The remapping-issue seems like a common Steam OS and Arch issue. There is a `client.conf` file in `/etc/pulse/`.

```
; default-sink =
; default-source =
; default-server =
; default-dbus-server =

autospawn = no
; autospawn = yes
; daemon-binary = /usr/bin/pulseaudio
; extra-arguments = --log-target=syslog

; cookie-file =

; enable-shm = yes
; shm-size-bytes = 0 # setting this 0 will use the system-default, usually 64 MiB

; auto-connect-localhost = no
; auto-connect-display = no
```

But nothing more. I founded this old thread on [ArchLinux.org](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=219333) and this newer one [How do I configure PulseAudio for 7.1 Surround Sound over HDMI?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111428/how-do-i-configure-pulseaudio-for-7-1-surround-sound-over-hdmi?newreg=49c78da6a3604d95bf74a77e1c1be30b)
I already posted a [bug report on Steam](https://steamcommunity.com/app/1675200/discussions/1/6117591738156470409/), but I don't think Valve prioritized this issue.

The solution in the last thread, has the biggest change of success. But I am not sure if this would work on Steam OS (based on Arch). Looking at [PulseAudio/Examples](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Examples#Remap_left_(or_right)_input_to_mono_for_stereo_use), just gives me a headache :p. Does anyone have an idea? The goal is running a .sh script when I want to switch to 5.1. (a permanent solution would be even more great).

Answer (score 1):

Valve fixed the issue in their latest beta: https://steamcommunity.com/app/1675200/discussions/0/3410929607716145819/

```
Fixed multi-channel audio on external displays
```

Not sure if this because I reported this bug: https://steamcommunity.com/app/1675200/discussions/1/6117591738156468815/. But I am glad it works :D.